# Reaction to multiple disordered Linux Program prompts (using expect, tcl, or otherwise)

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, expect

I have a program I would like to navigate that is a little too annoying for my expect skills.  As an example, consider it has 3 prompts that require 3 answers:
Name:
Question 1:
Question B:

Now if N, 1, and B came in that order every time, I'd be set.  Unfortunately for me, this particular program can elect to prompt in any order, depending on inputs or how the wind is blowing in the student's living room.... who knows.... We'll also be running it many times in a row.  I'll leave "and can ask Question 1 or Question One, and wants the same answer" for a different day.....

Is there a way to easily monitor for an arbitrary prompt at the same time as another?  Some kind of extended if/then or switch statement?  I suspect I am going to be working with $expect_out and exp_continue....  I would also want the ability to set arbitrary responses.... for example, I might respond to Name with "Bob" then "Joe" on the second run.

Thanks!

I'm still in the research stage, and will be testing code later, but I was hoping to find better pointers than my search results in case this is not nearly so difficult as I am making out to be...

Comment: I've found Python's `pexpect` much friendlier to use. You can [pass multiple patterns](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect) and the index of the matched pattern is returned.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can listen for multiple different things in an `expect` command, yes.

Comment: take a look at my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you are more confortable with bash/shells.

Answer (score 2):

As Shawn points out, Expect has no problem to wait for multiple prompts in parallel.  You need something like this:

```
set name_answer {Joe Bloggs}
set q1_answer {Stuff}
set qb_answer {Other stuff}

expect {
    NamePrompt {send "$name_answer\r"; exp_continue}
    Q1Prompt   {send "$q1_answer\r"; exp_continue}
    QBPrompt   {send "$qb_answer\r"; exp_continue}
    NextPrompt
}
```

Here `NextPrompt` would be something that indicates the end of this sequence of questions, so we break out of the loop.

For more details check the documentation at https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html